# How can i calculate (number + percentage) in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a C++ noob and sorry for my bad English.

I am having trouble to displaying percentage. I want to show this on output: Number + Percentage
For example: Number is 50 and Percentage is 20% . i want c++ code that calculate (Number + 20%) and showing Result: 60 .

I do not how to calculate this: Result = Number + 20% ;
I would be most grateful for some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

For floating point math you'll want to use the `double` type for double precision floating point. Then it's just math.

```
double number = 50;
double percent = 0.20;
double result = number * (1 + percent);
```

Display with `std::cout`:

```
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

Comment: It could also be `number + number * percent`.